# Jquery data attributes not working

Tags: jquery

Hello I'm trying to data attributes jQuery to my Userscript that I'm creating.

```
$('#divID .classsample').data('image');
```

Comment: Please post relevant markup. Also, what's not working?

Comment: try: `$('#divID .classsample').data('image',"test");` `alert($('#divID .classsample').data('image'));` `alert($('#divID .classsample').data('image').length);` your error should be somehwere else

Comment: Is there a reason why you're calling .classamble trough a id? Cant you just cal it trough $('.classsample').data('image');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not actually understand what you need , but try to set some value ( `url` for example) to your `data` property:

```
$('#divID .classsample').data('image' , url);
```

In case if  "to data attributes" means "to *set* data attributes"

Answer (score 0):

You can make this as the following:

```
var div = $("#divID .classsample");
    jQuery.data(div, "image", "url");
    alert(jQuery.data(div, "image"));
```